# Sum of all elements of each subarray

Tags: java, arrays

I was solving Kadane's algorithm , a very weird approach came to my mind while solving it. What if we find a way to find out the sum of all the elements of all possible subarrays forming from an array and store it in an arraylist. I've been thinking about it for a long time now, but I'm unable to solve it. It would be great if I can get some assistance.

`

```
 import java.util.*;
 import java.lang.*;
 import java.io.*;

class Sample
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // your code goes here
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int[] arr = new int[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            arr[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        int sum=0;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            sum+=arr[i];
        }
        list.add(sum);
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            list.add(arr[i]);
        }
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            //sum-=arr[i];
            if(!list.contains(sum-arr[i]) && (sum-arr[i])>0){
                list.add(sum-arr[i]);
            }
            sum=sum-arr[i];
        }
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

`

This is what I've done till now. There's a very big flaw in the logic and I know it but I just can't seem to solve it.

Comment: *What if we find a way to find out the sum of all the elements of all possible subarrays forming from an array and store it in an arraylist*, your code is not doing that.

Comment: also this is not a very good method because as the size of array increases, the number of possible subarrays increases rapidly, thus increasing computational complexity. If the size of the array is n, then the time complexity of this solution is O(n²) which is not very good.

Comment: Well, if you assume that the entire array is a subarray of itself and each element is also a subarray,  for an array of size `N` there will be `N(N+1)/2` subarrays and therefore the size of the resulting array of sums.  And you can use that to help determine if you are on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't use Kadanes algorithm, but it does sum the sub arrays.  It is facilitated by using the `subList` method of the `List` interface.

```
for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
    List<Integer> list =
            IntStream.range(1, i+1).boxed().toList();
    List<Integer> sums = new ArrayList<>();
    findsubs(list, 0, list.size(), sums);
    System.out.println(sums);
    sums.clear();
}
```

prints

```
[1]
[3, 2, 1]
[6, 5, 3, 3, 2, 1]
[10, 9, 7, 4, 6, 5, 3, 3, 2, 1]
[15, 14, 12, 9, 5, 10, 9, 7, 4, 6, 5, 3, 3, 2, 1]
[21, 20, 18, 15, 11, 6, 15, 14, 12, 9, 5, 10, 9, 7, 4, 6, 5, 3, 3, 2, 1]
[28, 27, 25, 22, 18, 13, 7, 21, 20, 18, 15, 11, 6, 15, 14, 12, 9, 5, 10, 9, 7, 4, 6, 5, 3, 3, 2, 1]
```

The method

```
    
public static void findsubs(List<Integer> list, int s, int e,
        List<Integer> sums) {
    if (s >= e) {
        return;
    }
    for (int i = s; i < e; i++) {
        sums.add(list.subList(i, e).stream()
                .mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum());
    }
    findsubs(list, s, e - 1, sums);
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
long subarraySum(vector<long> &A) {
    long result = 0;
    int n = A.size();
    for (int i=0; i <n; ++i)
    {
        result +=(A[i]*(i+1)*(n-i));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Sum of all sub array means,
Actually each element how many time contribute himself in each sub array
lets take : [1 2 3 4][0,0][0,1][1,1][0,2][1,2][2,2][0,3][1,3][2,3][3,3]

contribution of ith element is A[i]*(i+1)*(n-i)